# Using Top in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Contacts`, parent to table `Activity`. I would like to select the latest activity for each contact, but getting more than one row.

This is my query:

```
select top 30 
     * 
from 
     Contacts o, Activity d  
where 
     o.ID = d.contact 
     and d.ID > 401061 
     and Last_Action is null 
order by 
     d.activity_date desc
```

I think I need Top? but not sure how to implement here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want the latest activity _for each contact_?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to number each contact's activities.  In an outer query, you can filter down to only the latest activity per contact:

```
select  top 30 * 
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by o.ID
                    order by d.activity_date desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Contacts o
        join    Activity d
        on      o.ID = d.contact 
        where   d.ID > 401061 
                and Last_Action is null 
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only last activity per contact
order by 
         activity_date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `not exists` that will work on most dbs. You're basically selecting each activity per contact where a newer activity does not exist (therefore it's the latest activity).

```
select top 30 * from activity a
join contact c on c.id = a.contact
where not exists (
    select 1 from activity b
    where b.contact = a.contact
    and b.activity_date > a.activity_date
) and last_action is null and a.id > 401061
order by a.activity_date desc
```

Comment: Did you mean `b.activity_date > a.activity_date` instead of `b.id > a.id` ?  And you'll need an `order by` clause for the `top 30` to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is slight guesswork as I can't see what your tables look like in terms of columns, but perhaps this (or something like it) would work?

```
select top 30 * from Contacts o, 
(SELECT contact, max(activity_date) FROM Activity GROUP BY contact) d  
    where o.ID = d.contact And d.ID > 401061 
    and Last_Action is null order by d.activity_date desc
```

Comment: what if I want 30 contacts with latest activity each?

Comment: Ah...I get it. Sorry - thought was too simple a fix.

Comment: Eep at the 1980's join syntax... why not use SQL-92's `inner join ... on` ?

Comment: I was trying to keep it similar to the OPs original query

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 30 *
FROM
  Contacts AS o,
  ( SELECT
      contact,
      MAX( activity_date ) AS activity_date
    FROM
      Activity
    WHERE
      contact > 401061 AND
      Last_Action IS NULL
    GROUP BY
      contact
  ) AS d
WHERE
  o.ID = d.contact
ORDER BY
  d.activity_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the top 30 actions per contact, this is the exact kind of thing `CROSS APPLY` was invented for.

Something like the following - uncertainties are because I can't see an example of your data.

```
select
    *
from
    contacts
    cross apply (
        select top 30
            *
        from
            activity
        where
                contacts.id = activity.contact
                and 401061 < activity.id
    ) as _ca
where
    last_action is null -- Perhaps you could move this into the CA - but we don't know which table it's from
order by
    activity.activity_date desc;
```

## edit

```
select top 30
    *
from
    contacts
    cross apply (
        select top 1
            *
        from
            activity
        where
            contacts.id = activity.contact
            and 401061 < activity.id
        order by
            activity.activity_date desc
    ) as _ca
where
    last_action is null -- assuming this is in table contacts
order by
    _ca.activity_date desc;
```

Comment: This will look for the latest 30 activities per user.  The OP is looking for the 30 most recently active users.

Comment: "I would like to select the latest activity for contact". I think I can be forgiven for interpreting that the way I did. (Edit: OK, I've now seen the update below.) - aaaand added a new suggestion accordingly.

Comment: The edited version should work correctly.  But `cross apply` will force a subquery execution for each row in `contacts`, so I'd expect the other queries here to be much faster.

Comment: I tend to use this method because I typically look for more than 1 `top` value, which of course `max` can't handle. Yeah, perhaps in single cases, this is less efficient. Can the query optimiser not do anything clever here? - However, I suppose it depends on the data and execution environment - since in one case, you pull through all the (numbered) rows and then filter them; in the other, you query per row but filter as you go.

Comment: Never know about the query optimizer :)  But I'd be surprised if it would rewrite this. A `cross apply` usually means the programmer wants a correlated subquery.

Comment: it would have been much more helpful to the OP if you used aliases instead of the entire table.  this is especially important with extremely long table names that can clutter up the query.  here's a quick tutorial http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm

Comment: Are you really this petty? Not to mention that meaningless 1-letter table aliases hurt sense almost as much as ancient join syntax. But nice try at holding a grudge, I guess.

Comment: @underscore_d i'm not being petty.  just trying to help you out in the future.   `401061 < activity.id` is probably the least declarative-of-intent syntax you could possible use.   it's why no other answer has it like that

Answer (score 0):

Using a cte

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact ORDER BY activity_date DESC) rn
    FROM   Activity
    WHERE  d.ID > 401061  AND Last_Action IS NULL 
)
SELECT TOP 30 * 
FROM Contacts o 
     JOIN cte d  ON o.Id = d.contact 
WHERE d.rn = 1
ORDER BY cte.activity_date DESC
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick - using pre-1992 style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Yeah, this is not really any better than the `where` join used by the OP.

Comment: it made sense to the OP so that's why i left it

Comment: It would have been much more helpful to the OP to quickly point out that the standard has evolved and there are much better ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: @underscore_d define much better.. you mean visually? even though i use `JOIN` personally, that seems like personal preference.

Comment: Some of the non-visual reasons are provided in the very link above.

Comment: Look, most of the reasons are pitfalls, meaning that the old syntax can lead to confusion for new users, unexpected accidents for old users, and a lot of wasted time on sites like this. I'm not going to debate this here, or read for people, when the point is that the language provides a better, more declarative-of-intent syntax that can really help to minimise unintended consequences.